# The last version of non-preview asp .net core 3 in azure pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-pipelines

What is the command to install .net core 3.0 non preview in azure pipeline ?

I tried with

```
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install .net core 3.0'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.0.100'
```

And the build failed with

```
Getting URL to download .NET Core sdk version: 3.0.100.

Could not fetch download information for version 3.0.100. Please check if the version specified is correct. You can refer the link for supported versions => https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DotNetCoreInstallerV0/externals/releases.json. Falling back to creating convention based URL.

##[warning]Kindly upgrade to new major version of this task 'Use .NET Core (2.*)' for installing newer versions of .NET Core. '0.*' task version might not be able to download newer .NET core versions. To know more about 'Use Dot Net (2.*)', refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops. 3.0.100
```

before it worked :

```
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install .net core 3.0 (preview)'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.0.100-rc1-014190'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your download task, it worked fine with me.

However, You can have a try with the new installer task `UseDotNet@2`

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Install .NET Core 3.0 SDK
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.0.100'
```

Update:

In order to use .net3.0, You may need to use **DotnetCoreClI** tasks to **restore, build and test** your project, below is just for an example:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  project: "**/*.csproj"
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Install .NET Core 3.0 SDK
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.0.100'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
  displayName: Restore

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(project)'
  displayName: Build

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '$(project)'
  displayName: Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

This work for me, but with the command

> - task: UseDotNet@2

The build failed later at:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

```
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/TaxiGestion/TaxiGestion.csproj]
/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/TaxiGestionUnit/TaxiGestionUnit.csproj])
##[error]Packages failed to restore
```

the pool is ubuntu

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

Comment: I updated my answer, the reason this error occurred is probably because nuget command use its default sdk to compile the project. With `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task, your project  will be compiled with the newest version sdk. And also your following build, test task should use DotNetCoreCLI@2 task too.

Answer (score 0):

I am struck at same issue, but with different error

[image]

This is how I am executing the powershell script

```
$globaljson = '{"sdk": {"version": "3.0.100-preview3-010431"}}';
$globaljson | out-file $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet2
```

And this is how installer getting called.

[image]

Don't know what I am missing here.